# Erro Javascript button no IE9

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, button

Estou com um problema no browser somente no IE9, que ocorre na hora que eu carrego um anexo e quando eu clico no button incluir anexo (POST)
como imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
function uploadResponse(frameId) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Turma/AtualizarGridAnexo",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#divGridAnexo").html(data);//Fill div with results
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr);
            alert(ajaxOptions);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });


}

$("#adicionarAnexo").click(function (e) {


    var fileInput = $('#idAnexo');
    var maxSize = 5000000; //colocar valor em bytes
    var fname = $('#idAnexo[type=file]');
    console.log(fileInput.get(0).files[0].size);

    //pega o tamanho do arquivo
    if (fileInput.get(0).files.length) {
        var fileSize = fileInput.get(0).files[0].size;
        //verifica se é maior que 5MB
        if (fileSize > maxSize) {
            alert('Este arquivo é muito grande para ser anexado. Limite máximo permitido: 5MB.');
            return false;
        }
        //verifica se a extensão do arquivo é permitida
        var fileName = $('input[type=file]').val().toUpperCase();
        var regex = new RegExp("(.*?)\.(PDF|XLS|XLSX|DOC|DOCX|PPT|PPTX|MP3|WMA|AVI|PNG|JPG)$");
        if (!(regex.test(fileName))) {
            $('input[type=file]').val('');
            alert('Extensão não permitida, as extensões permitidas são: PDF, XLS, XLSX, DOC, DOCX, PPT, PPTX, MP3, WMA, AVI, PNG e JPG');
            return false;
        }
        //se o tamanho e a extensão for correta, faz upload do arquivo
        else {
           var tempFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
           tempFrame.src = "";
           tempFrame.onload = uploadResponse.bind(this, tempFrame);
           tempFrame.name = "tmpFrameUpload"
           this.appendChild(tempFrame);
           this.form.target = tempFrame.name;
           this.form.name = "uploadForm";
           this.form.acceptCharset = "UTF-8";
           //This is an example of a hidden input, used to pass extra vars to the server. Add more if you need them.
           //var tempNodePath = document.createElement("input");
           //tempNodePath.type = "hidden";
           //tempNodePath.value = [dir]; //if you want specify a target path.
           //tempNodePath.name = "filePath";
           //this.form.insertBefore(tempNodePath, this.form.childNodes[0]);
           this.form.submit();
           jq.idAnexo.val('');
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

O **erro** ocorre no   **console.log**(fileInput.get(0).files[0].size);

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Já procurei por aqui mas nao achei nada parecido...

Desde já agradeço galera!!

Debug do console...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você está tentando acessar um indice em files antes de verificar se existe algum arquivo, tente mover o `console.log(fileInput.get(0).files[0].size);` para dentro do bloco `if (fileInput.get(0).files.length) { ... }`

Comment: @TobyMosque Ele já esta la, mas sem **console.log**.

Comment: @Mariane, você debugar pelo console e verificou os dados de cada variável?

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert já sim, acabei de fazer isso e vi que é o meu  input[type=file]'). que não é suportado pelo browser do IE9. Porém não sei como mudar isso, o que colocar no lugar do input[type=file]').

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Editei a pergunta adicionando mais informações do debug do console...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mariane, a API para acessar arquivos em um `input[type='file']` não está implementada no IE9.

Abaixo a lista de browsers que dão suporte:

- Chrome 13
- Firefox 7
- Internet Explorer 10
- Opera 16
- Safari (WebKit) 6

Mais informações em [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/File) e [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi)

Como opção, você pode utilizar alguma blibioteca que emule um `input[type='file']` como o [FileAPI](https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI), ou convidar o usuario a atualizar o Browser com o [Outdated Browser v1.1.1](https://github.com/burocratik/Outdated-Browser/tree/master).

Comment: Editei a pergunta adicionando mais informações do debug do console...

Comment: não consigo visualizar as imagens no imgur.